# Является ли открытым файлом Сefsharp.dll 49той версии

Tags: c#, cefsharp

`Сefsharp.dll` (49 версия) - является ли он открытым файлом? Есть ли возможность редактирования библиотеки?

Дело в том, что 49 версия последняя из версий, которая поддерживает framework 4.0, который в свою очередь нужен для работы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что для вас такое "открытость файла"? Лицензия BSD вас устраивает? [CefSharp is BSD licensed, so it can be used in both proprietary and free/open source applications](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp), судя по [истории версий](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commits/master/LICENSE) ваша 49тая версия была выпущена в  2016 году (
49.0.1 от June 01, 2016)

Comment: есть ли возможность редактирования библиотеки?

Comment: Самой dll'ки? Нет, нету или это слишком извращённо. Или вы имеете ввиду форкнуться от какой-либо точки и править исходники? Технически есть, вот вам сорцы на гитхабе, а вот насчёт лицензионной чистоты лучше уточните у юристов.

Comment: А что вы такого собираетесь сделать с этой библиотекой?